# Unable to set IsSynced to true in Quote

Tags: apex, trigger

I am not able to set `IsSynced` to true in Quote in test classes. What I am doing is, I am making `SyncedCodeID` in Opportunity to true, This should make `IsSynced` to true in Quote.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set the `SyncedQuoteId` field on the opp with the quote you want to sync.

```
public static List<Quote> quotes;

static {
    this.quotes = getQuotes();
}

@testSetup
public static void TestSetup() {
    Account newAccount = TestDataFactory.newAccount();
    insert newAccount;

    Opportunity newOpp = TestDataFactory.newOpportunity(newAccount);
    insert newOpp;

    Quote newQuote = TestDataFactory.newQuote(newOpp);
    insert newQuote;

    newOpp.syncedQuoteId = newQuote.Id;
    update newOpp;
}

@isTest
public static test() {
    for (Quote q : quotes) {
        system.assert(q.isSyncing);
    }
}

public static List<Quote> getQuotes() {
    return [
        SELECT IsSyncing
        FROM Quote
    ];
}
```

**Make sure you actually re-query for the quote. If you do not re-query the quote, the field will not be updated.** This is one of the many reasons I recommend a pattern like this for test classes.